# Connect to WebSphere MQ from Spring using Spring configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-dsl

I am using Spring DSL of Apache Camel in our project which is a Spring Boot application. We are connecting to various MQs like Apache ActiveMQ "Classic," Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, and IBM MQ in our project to send and receive messages. We are able to successfully connect to Apache ActiveMQ "Classic" and ActiveMQ Artemis using the below configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${provider.url}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${security.principal}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${security.credentials}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactoryT24" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" primary="true">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>${connectionFactory}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="jmsT24" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jboss.jms.concurrentConsumers}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am now trying to figure out how to connect to IBM MQ and what all parameters to pass to create the connection factory like how to pass queue manager and channel information but unable to do so as it is not working, can anyone please provide what would be the InitialContextFactory and how to pass parameters for creating connection factory?

Comment: Have you tried searching those two tags here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot+ibm-mq

Comment: Is [source](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/blob/testing/boot-mq-bridge/src/main/resources/spring/camel-context.xml) helpful?

Comment: Hi Josh - I have tried searching but got no useful result.

Comment: Hi Doug - The Github link contains the information I was looking for. Will try to connect using this method and get back if there are any errors. Thanks a lot.